# Puppet dependancy management

Tags: dependencies, puppet, standards

Suppose I have a class that installs packages(`profile::base::tools`) and another class that defines the yumrepos(`profile::base::yum`) required for those packages.

tools.pp:

```
class profile::base::tools {
   $packages = [
      'package1',
      'package2'
   ]

   package { $packages:
     ensure => present,
   }
}
```

Currently the way it is run is through base.pp:

base.pp:

```
include profile::base::yum 
include profile::base::tools

Class['profile::base::yum'] -> [
    Class['profile::base::tools']]
```

So when I run `base.pp` it creates the yum repos first and then installs the packages. Currently the dependency that the `tools.pp` requires yumrepos defined first is only mentioned in the `base.pp`.

My question is if I run `tools.pp` alone(for testing purposes) it wont know about the dependency and hence fail. I can add `include profile::base::yum` in the `tools.pp` class but wanted to know if its a standard for each class to know about dependencies even if its already defined elsewhere(like in `base.pp`)

Comment: Instead of `Class['profile::base::yum'] -> Class['profile::base::tools']`, you should probably use `require yum` in the `tools` class: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_relationships.html#syntax-the-require-function.

Comment: See comments to the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is if I run tools.pp alone(for testing purposes) it wont
>   know about the dependency and hence fail. I can add include
>   profile::base::yum in the tools.pp class but wanted to know if its a
>   standard for each class to know about dependencies even if its already
>   defined elsewhere(like in base.pp)

This is one of the key differences between public classes and private classes.  Public classes are those that are intended for users of your module to declare directly, whereas private classes are those that are supposed to be declared only by other classes belonging to the same module.  This public / private distinction itself is primarily a matter of documentation and convention, but although the language has no direct support for class privacy, the `puppet/stdlib` module does have [an assert_private function](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/readme#assert_private) that can help you enforce the intended usage pattern.

For private classes, all these details are up to you.  Such classes are not meant to be declared directly, so it does not matter much whether they set up their own dependencies and relationships.  What's important is that all the needed dependencies and relationships are set up when a private class is declared by one of its module's public classes.

Public classes, on the other hand, ought to declare all their dependencies and arrange internally for any order-of-application requirements to be set up.  That ensures that all you need to do to use them is declare them, themselves.  There are many variations on how that can be done.  In your particular case, exactly the relationship that you currently set up in your `profile::base` class could be set up instead (or additionally) in `profile::base::tools`, by use of a `require` statement:

```
class profile::base::tools {
   # 'require' does everything 'include' does, plus establishes a relationship:
   require profile::base::yum

   # ...

}
```

Inasmuch as it is usually a good idea to be as specific as possible with your relationships, you might also consider being a bit more granular:

```
class profile::base::tools {
   include profile::base::yum

   $packages = [
      'package1',
      'package2'
   ]

   package { $packages:
     ensure  => present,
     require => Class['profile::base::yum'],
   }
}
```

That doesn't make a practical difference in this particular case, but it might be useful in other cases.  Note here that it is still appropriate to `include` `yum::profile::base` to ensure that it is in fact declared, even though the relationships with it are expressed at the resource level.

Comment: Definitely agree with the granular dependency mapping. That helps with reducing the change of a circular dependency due to implicit resource containment, and just is better practice in general. This whole answer has good best practices information and `assert_private` is such a helpful function for protecting against class misuse that we developers keep forgetting the usage.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear how you're actually doing your testing, but if you are using Rspec, then you can use `pre_condition` and `post_condition` for this, for example:

```rb
describe 'profile::base::tools' do
  let(:pre_condition) {
    """
    include profile::base::yum
    """
  }

  let(:post_condition) {
    """
    Class['profile::base::yum'] -> [
      Class['profile::base::tools']]
    """
  }

  it { is_expected.to contain_package('package1') }
  it { is_expected.to contain_package('package2') }
end
```

Rspec then internally builds a manifest with the class you declare/test wrapped between the pre and post condition.

Of course, you don't really need the post condition; putting both inside the pre_condition is fine as the ordering of this code doesn't actually matter, like this:

```rb
  let(:pre_condition) {
    """
    include profile::base::yum

    Class['profile::base::yum'] -> [
      Class['profile::base::tools']]
    """
  }
```

If you are not using Rspec, however, and you want to test this manually or in another automated way, the principle is the same: whenever you declare the tools class, also declare the supporting code, including the dependent class and the relationship declarations.

Comment: I understand how to run them together. My question is more around the thought that a class should know about its dependencies regardless of testing. This gives the added advantage that the spec need not care about the dependencies when testing as the class knows about them. Is this wrong?

Comment: I see the advantage of it, but it's just not how Puppet works. The relationships between classes, for better or worse, exist outside of the classes.

Comment: Also, your spec tests shouldn't _need_ to care about their dependencies when you are unit testing them. I have shown how to do it in case you do really need to do so, for some reason unspecified, e.g. if one class depends on a resource in another class.

Comment: **'The relationships between classes, for better or worse, exist outside of the classes'** : Are you saying that having the class know about its dependencies is a bad practice or is not possible at all? I thought if I add `include profile::base::yum` in `tools.pp` would make it a dependency in `tools.pp` Or a `require profile::base::yum`

Comment: I guess it depends what you mean by "know about". If you mean you want to declare a class tools and have it known from within the context of the tools class that the class requires class yum, that's not possible.

Comment: Actually, you could always move the relationship `Class[yum] -> Class[tools]` inside the tools class. You could duplicate it inside the yum class for consistency. That would be very confusing though.

Comment: If I add `require Class[yum]` in `tools.pp`, will it not know that there's a dependency on `profile::base::yum`??

Comment: That's essentially the same as what I just said above. But you wouldn't do that because it would be bad style (e.g. violates action-at-a-distance principle).

Comment: I should add that if you meant the `require` _function_, then you're correct, as per the answer above. By your notation I thought you meant `require => Class[yum]` i.e. the metaparameter require.